# Keyboard gives bad ascii values

Tags: keyboard

I poured water over my notebook this morning.
  When i turn it on, it works, but integrated keyboard doesn't work.
 It gives totally wrong ascii values.
What can be done now?

Comment: Contact the service centre!

Comment: Use the on-screen keyboard with the mouse

Comment: now i cant even turn notebook on... great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing is to disconnect power cables and battery until the laptops internals have fully dried up to prevent any short circuits.

If problem still exists after, you can call their service center if you still have warranty.

If not, you can try to find a replacement keyboard on ebay or directly from laptop manufacturer. This assuming it's only the keyboard circuit board that's toasted

Comment: i guess i should have wait to dry it up.. so now that i didnt wait... now its dead?